# How to make event.path recognize elements inside an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To demonstrate my question, here's my version of HTML:

```
<body>
  <a href="google.com">
    <div>
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      <h4>Venus</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</body>
```

Then I use 'onclick' for the body in Javascript:

```
document.body.onclick = function(event) {
  console.log(event.path)
}
```

When I click on the 'h2' tag, the console will log only [window, html, body, a] and not the elements inside of the 'a' tag.

The result I want is when I click the 'h2' tag, event.path will return an array of [window, html, body, a, div, h2]

This problem also exists with the 'p' tag.

Is there a way for the 'event.path' to includes elements inside 'a' tags? Thank you very much.

Comment: can you try with .children()  or .parent() using jquery?

Comment: i cannot replicate your problem. it works fine  > https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/34438/  . Also i suggest not to wrap a block element inside an inline element. Is not good practice. And if you have other links inside the `a` or buttons etc. that's forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you

```js
function handleClicks(e) {
    var path = [];
    var node = e.target;

    while(node != document) {
       !e.target.contains(node.parentNode) && path.push(node.nodeName); // if you want to exclude the elements inside the clicked element
       node =  node.parentNode;
    }
    console.log(path);
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', handleClicks);
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="#" id="not">
    <div>
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      <h4>Venus</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</body>
```

Edited

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid using "div" inside anchor tag instead you can use "span" with some defined user classes on which required.